# jquery a href recognition

Tags: jquery

I have a page in which there are multiple hrefs. i want to find out which href is clicked and based on that href click I want to show and hide a div?

Comment: This is not a free coding service. Show us what you have tried and we can help you fill in the blanks. This is just a blatant show me the codz. Put some effort in.

Comment: @Delan - refrain from tagging questions like this, it's been discussed at length on meta.

Comment: redsquare - You wrote as you are aware of my efforts

Comment: @redsquare - there's a fine line between saying "I don't know how to do this, can someone show me" and saying "I need a solution, please write it for me."  I'm not sure, in the case where you really just don't know how, if the more reasonable thing to do isn't just to ask someone who knows rather than struggle with something I'm completely clueless to solve.  To someone who's never even heard of a regex, figuring out how to extract just the right bit from a url to associate with a particular div might just fall into that category.

Comment: @redsquare - and it is *exactly* a free coding service, if you happen to end up here via search and find a solution rather than ask a question.  I suggest saving your indignation for the questions where someone asks for a big solution instead of a little thing.  While I'm ok with *helping* someone do their job, I'm not ok with *doing* their job.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Nick. Just out of curiosity, could I have a link?

Comment: +1 cause i hate useless downvoters! s*ck*rs! ;-)

Comment: @tvanfosson in your opinion, however the upvotes to my comment suggest your opinion is in the minority.

Comment: If you have a lot of links/divs, have you considered using the jQuery UI accordion (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

Comment: @Delan - absolutely, here's the thread: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/whats-the-difference-between-an-obvious-homework-question-and-one-tagged-plzsend

Comment: @redsquare - it's not a competition.  it's just my opinion that this question isn't that egregious.

Comment: @redsquare - In cases like this actually showing bad attempts may *confuse* rather than help answerers. A clear description of a simple problem is better than code that doesn't work.  Programmers to to look at the code and try and guess what they're after, while a description is much more useful, seeing as the code didn't work.  If there's a flaw to correct, code is better of course...if it's a simple problem then a *good* description is far more helpful in my opinion.

Comment: @tvanfosson you have too much time on your hands. I am glad my other questions on SO did not rattle you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have control over the href's here and you want to have the simplest markup possible, in that case you can do something like this:

```
<a href="#div1">Toggle Div 1</a>
<a href="#div2">Toggle Div 2</a>

<div id="div1" class="toggleDiv">Div 1 Content</div>
<div id="div2" class="toggleDiv">Div 2 Content</div>
```

Then to open/toggle a div based on the `href`, or more specifically the `hash` property, you can do this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(".toggleDiv").not(this.hash).hide();
    $(this.hash).toggle('fast');
});​​​
```

This toggles the corresponding `<div>` with the matching `ID == href` minus the hash and hides the other `<div>` elements if that's what you're after...you do this by just giving them a common class and hide all those except the one related to the current link.

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aYEUG/) to see if it's what you're after.

Comment: +1 This is a good solution for the problem you describe.  It tends to degrade gracefully when javascript is turned off.  Many tab/accordion plugins work exactly this way.  I wish I had thought to add it to my examples.  For some reason I *always* think of hrefs as complete urls.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler to the anchor:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        // test the href and show/hide the div:
        $('#someDiv').show();

        // return false to avoid following the link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you something to start with:

```
$('a').click(function()
{
    var href = this.href;

    // Show/hide your div.
    return false;
});
```

Just implement your logic in the `click` handler function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
$(function(){
 $('a').click(function(){
   alert('I was clicked, here my href = ' +  $(this).attr('href'));
   $('#div_id').slideToggle('slow'); // show hide div
   return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to choose the div based on the href, and that can be done, but it's relatively hard compared to some other mechanisms.  Typically, I find that there is some relationship in the DOM structure that I can exploit instead or I can add classes to the link/div to make the solution simpler.  For example, it's often the case that the link is next to or in the same container as the div to show.  In this case you can traverse the DOM and select the div that is the sibling or a child of the same container.

Some examples:

Link in the same container

```
 $('a.menu-item').click( function() {
      $('div.content').hide(); // hide all items
      $(this).parent().find('div.content').show(); // show associated item
 });
```

Link in the same order as the divs

```
 $('a.menu-item').click( function() {
      var index = $('a.menu-item').eq(this).index();  // get index
      $('div.content').hide().eq(index).show(); // hide all, show corresponding
 });
```

With the same class (assumes link as a single, unique, shared class with div)

```
 $('a').click( function() {
     $('div.content').hide();
     $('div').hasClass( $(this).attr('class') ).show();
 });
```